# How to make showBottomSheet continue to slide when showBottomSheet contains scrollable widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

When showBottomSheet contains scrollable widgets, after sliding down the [Scrollable widget] to the top, the showBottomSheet cannot continue to slide down, how to solve? Similar to the comment in Tik Tok.

Comment: did you tried the built in flutter widget DraggableScrollableSheet?

Answer (score 0):

using the built in widget DraggableScrollableSheet, this should be pretty simple:

```cs
showBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      maxChildSize: 0.5, // playing with these  4 
      minChildSize: 0.25, // values will give you 
      initialChildSize: 0.5, // different and interesting results
      expand: false,
      builder: (context, controller) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: controller,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(i.toString()),
                )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Think you very much.

Comment: Think you very much.

Comment: Youre welcome! can you mark the answer as right if it worked for you?

Comment: Wait... I found that DraggableScrollableSheet did not meet my expectations. DraggableScrollableSheet will create a dark background, and I don't need this dark background. And no matter how to set maxChildSize, minChildSize, and initialChildSize in DraggableScrollableSheet, it can not be achieved like Tik Tok's comment. Is there any other way to solve my question?

Comment: When the parameters are set to the following:
             maxChildSize: 0.5,
             minChildSize: 0.2,
             initialChildSize: 0.5,
             expand: false,
When sliding to the range of 0.2~0.5, it cannot be rebound to 0.5

Comment: And when showBottomSheet is followed by sliding down, I just slide down slowly, and showBottomSheet is directly slipped to the bottom instead of following the position of my finger.